# Does CPLEX concert technology has its own version number?

Tags: c++, cplex

For example, I am using CPLEX optimization studio 12.4. For sure, 12.4 is version number of CPLEX. But, my friend asked me what is the version of the C++ concert technology/library inside the CPLEX 12.4. I had no clue, and in fact, I believed that concert should share the same version number as its associated CPLEX, i.e. also 12.4. Was I correct? Maybe I misunderstood it. I looked the installation directory on my Ubuntu, I found that the Concert library resides in the folder called "/opt/cplex124/concert/lib/x86-64_sles10_4.1/static_pic". Is 10_4.1 a version number for concert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concert and CPLEX have the same version numbers.

ILOG Concert has never been a separate product.  It was considered part of CPLEX or their Constraint Programming products (ILOG Solver/Scheduler/Dispatcher).  Despite this, back in the day of ILOG concert technology 1.0 (around 2001), CPLEX was at version 7 and ILOG Solver/Scheduler was at 4.0.  This continued with concert 2.0 and CPLEX 9.  By the time CPLEX 10.0 was released, ILOG synched up the version numbers.

Comment: Thanks, @David for your detailed answer. Glad to know the version CPLEX history back in ILOG era. Btw, I was trying to up-vote your answer, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to do that.